# What is wrong in this code php?

Tags: php, html

What is wrong in this code php ?
 netbeans 8.1 program have been tried and when I write $ _GET problem that occurs

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
      if ($_GET['button']) {
      
      if ($_GET['name']) {

       echo "Your Name Is".$_GET['name'];
      }else {
       echo "Plz Enter your Name";
      }
}
 ?>
 <div>
  <label for="name">Name :</label>
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" for="name" />
 </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not see your `<form>` tag

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: Oh my god I forgot this matter
I'm sorry but I'm a programmer tyro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten the form tag:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="name">Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" for="name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you did not start form tags second you have to define the post type and then submit

```
<form class="" role="form" method="get" action="yourfile.php"></form>
```